# Can users completely new to our iOS app still login with Facebook Graph API v1.0 if we specify v1.0 in the SDK as directed by Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

We know how to call Facebook Graph API v1.0 and are calling it in the iOS SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading) but new users are getting treated as though they're signing up with v2.0.

We know that once a user logs in via Graph API v2.0, there is no going back to v1.0 for that individual user (http://code-worrier.com/blog/changes-in-facebook-graph-api-2-dot-0/) but does anyone know if all new users to your app will automatically login through v2.0 and only previous users can login v1.0? We're using the Facebook iOS SDK v3.14.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

New users signing up for your application since 4/30/2014 will return app-scoped id's.  The version you use in the URL for the API request won't change that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I noticed that, which worries me, but what's most valuable to us is getting access to their full friend list if the user grants us permission (v1.0). And right now we're only able to show their friends who already have the app (v2.0). Facebook has written everywhere that they will support Graph API v1.0 until 4/30/15.

Comment: Regardless of when they registered, there's no more full friends list.  You have to use invitable_friends or taggable_friends.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it! The odd thing is all of our existing users, who had the app prior to 4/30/14, are still able to see their whole friend list when they go to make a group (which is the main focus of the app), even those friends who are not on the app. And Facebook has said they're going to support the versioned API and v1.0, which would mean you should be able to call the friend_list in v1.0 I would think.

Comment: My bad..  It will only work for people who registered before 4/30/2014.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what we found out: you can still log into / use the old version of the Facebook API (v1.0). The issue is the API version that gets called by your app depends on the Facebook iOS SDK version you are using in your app. So if you want to jump back to pre-v2.0 Facebook API, you need to be using an old version of the Facebook iOS SDK (3.13.1 and previous). They are all found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads

Keep in mind, Facebook is forcing developers to upgrade to v2.0 by April 30th of 2015. But, if you have a v2.0 headache now that you don't want to fix right away, this a decent band-aid solution. In our app, we upgraded the Facebook iOS SDK to get compliant with Apple's IDFA regulations, not knowing we were upgrading to v2.0 of the Facebook API. Since our app uses some features no longer available in v2.0, this was a huge issue.

Any users that may have signed up for your app while you were using v2.0 may need to delete app related info on Facebook so that they can log in fresh when you jump back to v1.0. This will allow you to get real Facebook user IDs and not app scoped user IDs.

The last small hurdle is that Apple is now rejecting many, if not all, apps that use the IDFA. All Facebook SDKs that use v1.0 use the IDFA (to my knowledge). The only way around it is to tell Apple that you are using it, but that it is attributed to a previously served advertisement (you do this on iTunes connect). See this article here: http://www.adexchanger.com/mobile/apple-throws-a-bone-to-app-marketers-blesses-idfa-for-attribution/

Again, this is not necessarily a 'proper' solution, but if you don't have the bandwidth / resources to fix your v2.0 issues right now, it can definitely help. Just make sure to get back to v2.0 before April 30, 2015.